how can recyclerview central item highlight?
At first, I tried to use a view pager, but due to the overall size issue of the view pager, I didn't think it was right to implement such a screen.
So I started using Recycler View and even worked on an infinite loop screen.
I'm trying to think of a way to change the background color by adjusting only the median among the displayed positions, but I can't.
I want to Scolled changing background
How do I create a view like this? I think the view pager will be difficult because it is full screen.
I want to give a highlight by changing the background color like this. What method should I use?


This is one solution.
onItemCLick store the position in variable somewhere out of Adapter class like in Constant

var selectedPosition : Int

class then call notifyDataSetChanged().
then replace onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView's Adapter
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder , position: Int) {
      if(Constant.selectedPosition == position){
          holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_bg)
      } else {
          holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected_bg)
      }
    }


The item in the center is highlighted when scrolled, not when clicked.
